# call jBPM6 webservice using REST API

Tags: java, drools, jbpm

We have developed some workflows on jBPM6 which is deployed on one server, now we want to access the methods using rest client from our JAVA program, can anybody please guide us how to start.

Regards,
Jay

Answer (score 1):

Look at the docs please

http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0.1/userguide/jBPMRemoteAPI.html

17.1.1. The REST Remote Java RuntimeEngine Factory